# Android: How to set view to scroll away while positioning it between two pinned views?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I have a fixed toolbar, a view with layout_scrollFlags="scroll", a fixed view for filtering and a recycler view, in this respective order from top to bottom in a CoordinatorLayout.

This is what I have been able to achieve so far:

[image: Current behavior]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollAwayView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Scroll Away View"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/fixedToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/apl_grayscale_050"
            app:title="Fixed Toolbar"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/black" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:singleLine="true" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The issue is:** That the positioning is incorrect. The fixed toolbar should be on top while the scroll away view should be between the two pinned views: the fixed toolbar and the chip group list.

I read that the `layout_scrollFlags=scroll` has no effect when any sibling views
before this one do not have this flag. Any ideas on how I can achieve this behavior while keeping the position?

Desired positioning:[image: Desired positioning]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution today, after a lot of trial and error.

**The Solution**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/fixedToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:title="Fixed Toolbar"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/black" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fixedToolbar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollAwayView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Scroll Away View"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                    android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:singleLine="true" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The key points here:**

- Place the view which is positioned on top of the scrollable layout, the `fixedToolbar` in a view that is outside of the parent Coordinator layout.
- For this solution I used ConstraintLayout to be the parent of the `fixedToolbar` and the CoordinatorLayout that is the parent of the rest of the view.

**How I arrived at this solution**

Inspecting the `layout_scrollFlags`, I saw the following information about the `scroll` flag:

> The view will be scroll in direct relation to scroll events. This flag
> needs to be set for any of the other flags to take effect. If **any sibling**
> views before this one do not have this flag, then this value has **no
> effect**.

Because I needed to position a view above the `scrollAwayView` I placed it in a view outside the Coordinator parent. Now that the `fixedToolbar` and the `scrollAwayView` are not sibling views, while being placed in the correct arrangement.

[image]